# How to save a group of registers and restore them later?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-registers, instruction-set

The following example from the book *Arm System Developers Guide* shows an `STM` increment before instruction followed by an `LDM` decrement after instruction.

```
PRE r0 = 0x00009000
r1 = 0x00000009
r2 = 0x00000008
r3 = 0x00000007
STMIB r0!, {r1-r3}
MOV r1, #1
MOV r2, #2
MOV r3, #3

PRE(2) r0 = 0x0000900c
r1 = 0x00000001
r2 = 0x00000002
r3 = 0x00000003
LDMDA r0!, {r1-r3}
POST r0 = 0x00009000
r1 = 0x00000009
r2 = 0x00000008
r3 = 0x00000007
```

The `STMIB` instruction stores the values 7, 8, 9 to memory. We then corrupt register r1 to r3. The `LDMDA` reloads the original values and restores the base pointer r0.

But, the memory of r1, r2, r3 has been overwritten by 1,2,3. Then, how are the previous values restored. Where does it saves the old values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first operand of `LDM/STM` (`r0` in your examples) is the *base register*. That register holds the address in memory where the values in the register list will be stored.

So, for example, when you `STMIB r0!,{r1-r3}` with `r0==0x9000` you'll store the value of `r1` at address `0x9004`, `r2` at `0x9008`, and `r3` at `0x900C`. Note that none of the values are stored at address `0x9000`, because you used `IB` which means *increment (the address) before (storing/reading)*.
The `!` means that the final address (`0x900C`) will get written back to `r0`.

Then, when you do the `LDMDA r0!,{r1-r3}` you start out with `r0==0x900C`. `DA` means *decrement after*, so the address will be decremented after each register we load, and since the lowest register always gets transferred to/from the lowest memory address we start by loading `r3` from address `0x900C`, then `r2` from `0x9008`, and finally `r1` from `0x9004`.